# The State Repository Service service terminated with the following error: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: windows, windows-10, services, windows-services

I have started getting weird behaviour on my Windows 10 laptop, without really changing anything myself. For example, it's much slower, the start menu won't open and the powershell throws some error about PSReadline. I had a look in the event viewer and under system, it's all red with errors:

[image]

There are the 3 error which are most common:

1:

> The State Repository Service service terminated with the following
>   error:  The system cannot find the file specified.

2:

> The Tile Data model server service depends on the State Repository
>   Service service which failed to start because of the following error: 
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

3:

> DCOM got error "1068" attempting to start the service tiledatamodelsvc
>   with arguments "Unavailable" in order to run the server:
>   {B31118B2-1F49-48E5-B6F5-BC21CAEC56FB}

So it looks like it all starts with the State Repository Service not starting. I tried running it manually but get the following error:

> Windows could not start the State Repository Service service on Local
>   Computer.
>
> Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.

Looking at the registry entry, I have the following but can't tell if there's anything wrong:

[image]

I was able to find the `Windows.StateRepository.dll` in `C:/Windows/System32/`.

**How can I get the State Repository Service running?**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the 'parameters' and 'Security' keys are missing from the 'StateRepository' key in the registry.

Either restore the Service from a good, working SYSTEM registry hive, i.e. from another working Windows 10 version, export the service from HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services to a .reg file, and then merge it into your registry... or you can create the keys and enter the details manually.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### 1st Solution

The following should resolve the issue and *must be completed in the order listed*.

Issue the following in an admin terminal:

1. Cleanup the Component Store (`%WinDir%\WinSxS`):

   ```powershell
   DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
   ```
2. Check for and fix corruption within the Component Store, then *Reboot once completed*:

   ```powershell
   DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
   ```

   - This verifies the backups of all system files against known good copies from the Windows Update servers, so an internet connection is required.
   - If an internet connection cannot be obtained, you will need to use the Windows install ISO's `install.wim` or `install.esd`:

     1. Get the Image Index for the Windows install from the `install.wim`/`install.esd`

        ```powershell
        DISM /Get-Wiminfo /WimFile:"Z:\sources\install.wim"
        ```
     2. Use this in place of #2's command, then *Reboot once completed*:

        ```powershell
        DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:wim:"z:\sources\install.esd":<index#>
        ```
3. Check for and fix system file corruption, then *Reboot once completed*:

   ```powershell
   SFC /ScanNow
   ```

---

### 2nd Solution

You can also [restore](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322756/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows) a registry hive from the auto-created backup in `%WinDir%\System32\config\RegBack`

- ***Note:** A recent Windows 10 update disabled the auto-backup of hives and can be re-enabled via:*

  ```powershell
  Reg Add "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Configuration Manager" /v EnablePeriodicBackup /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
  ```

---

### 3rd Solution

Should neither of the above work, you can perform a repair install of Windows, which will keep all installed applications and data:

1. Download the [Windows install ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
2. Extract the ISO's contents to a folder on a drive other than `C:\`
3. While booted to Windows, run the Windows Install ISO's `Setup.exe`

   - Select *SKIP* if the Product Key is requested
   - Select to keep Settings/Files

This option should only be used if `DISM` and `SFC` [above] are unable to repair the corruption.